# Vietnamese text editor in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, text, translation

I have localized for FIGS and have added Vietnamese localization files, but the VN text files won't display in XCode 4.4. I get an empty editor.  Previews in finder look fine for these files, and they work in an older, released version.

Is there a setting some place to tell XCode to read these files as UNICODE rather than UTF8?

Or, do I have to change ALL my localization files to UNICODE?(it is UNICODE for Vietnamese, right?)

Or, do I just trust that the files are fine and ignore the fact that I can't display them in XCODE?

Comment: There's no such thing as "Unicode for Vitenamese". There is "Unicode" and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  I had the path wrong for the Vietnamese localization files.